# WPF ListBox that can sort by column

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a XAML file with only a ListBox.  I dynamically create the columns and add the rows.  with this code:

```
ListBoxItem l1 = new ListBoxItem();
StackPanel s1 = new StackPanel(); 
s1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
ContentPresenter ch1 = new ContentPresenter();
ch1.Content = "ICR";
s1.Children.Add(ch1); //just an example I add more than 1 column
li.Content = s1; 
listbox.items.add(l1);
```

Which works fine, but now I want to create column headers and sort by column.  Can I do that with a dynamically with a ListBox or am I going down the wrong path?

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple columns and column headers, don't use a `ListBox`... use a `ListView` or a `DataGrid` instead.

As for sorting, you will probably have to do it manually, because of the way you fill the list. It would be much easier if you were using data binding. About *everything* in WPF is easier when you start using binding...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this tutorial will be helpful.

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/wpf-sample-series-listbox-grouping-sorting-subtotals-and-collapsible-regions/